# Understanding server notifications for auto-renewable subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I enabled auto-renewable subscription (sandbox) and have the server-to-server notification set up.

When I purchase - I get two s2s notification types -

"INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL" - user just purchased
"RENEWAL" - the first auto renewal notification after about 5 minutes.

But after that -  I don't get any s2s notifications...shouldn't I be getting another 5 RENEWAL notifications.

During this period, I haven't opened the app to process the transaction queue.

But I assumed I would get the asyncronous s2s renewal notifications.

I'm trying to best tackle the issue of when the user has a valid subscription - detect cancellations etc.